# Assigning labels to rows when there exists some value in a row that is the same as another row

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am doing some data cleaning and I came across this problem. An example of my dataframe (some entries are missing) is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |  |
| 1 |  | 8 |
| 1 |  | 9 |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 |  | 5 |
|  |  | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
|  | 5 |  |

and my expected output dataframe is:

| A | B | C | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |  | 0 |
| 1 |  | 8 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 9 | 0 |
| 1 |  |  | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 |  | 5 | 1 |
|  |  | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 | 0 |
|  | 5 |  | 0 |

Are there ways in pandas/dplyr to get this output?

Edit: For example, the value 1 appears in the first 4 rows of A so these rows should have the same label. The 3rd row and 2nd last row has value 9 in column C so they should also have the same label. The last 2 rows have values 5 in column B so they should also be the same label. The 3rd last row does not have any values in the row that matches any value in the same column of any row so it is a unique label.

Comment: You need to be more explicit... what parameter are you using to label them?

Comment: I don't think there's a parameter here since it is comparing the rows as long as there exists 1 matching value in it

Comment: What if the next row is (A, B, C)=(5, 7, 5)? Should the label be 0 or 1?

Comment: In that case, the labels 0 and 1 should be the same label (make all the 1s zero or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish the task. In your example, there is a slight conflict with your comment. Since rows 8 and 9 have label 0 and contain 5's in at least one column, rows 5 and 6 should retroactively be changed to label 0, because they contain 5's in at least one column as well.

```
text="A B   C
1   7   NA
1   NA  8
1   NA  9
1   NA NA   
2   2   5
2   NA  5
3 NA NA
4   5   9
5 NA NA"
df=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
my_maps=list()
my_maps[[1]]=unique(unlist(df[1,]))
my_maps[[1]]=my_maps[[1]][!is.na(my_maps[[1]])]
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  currow=df[i,]
  currow=unique(unlist(currow))
  currow=currow[!is.na(currow)]
  boo=TRUE
  for (k in 1:length(my_maps)) {
    if (length(intersect(my_maps[[k]], currow))>0) {
      my_maps[[k]]=union(my_maps[[k]], currow)
      boo=FALSE
    }
  }
  if (boo) {
    my_maps[[length(my_maps)+1]]=currow
  }
}

i=1
while (i < length(my_maps)) {
  j=i+1
  while (j <= length(my_maps)) {
    if (length(intersect(my_maps[[i]], my_maps[[j]]))>0) {
      my_maps[[i]]=union(my_maps[[i]], my_maps[[j]])
      my_maps[[j]]=NULL
    }
    j=j+1
  }
  i=i+1
}

label=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:length(my_maps)) {
    if (length((intersect(my_maps[[j]], unique(unlist(df[i,])))))>0) {
      label[i]=j
      break
    }
  }
}

df=mutate(df, label=label-1)

  A  B  C label
1 1  7 NA     0
2 1 NA  8     0
3 1 NA  9     0
4 1 NA NA     0
5 2  2  5     0
6 2 NA  5     0
7 3 NA NA     1
8 4  5  9     0
9 5 NA NA     0
```